# A jar started with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() runs longer than from command line

Tags: java, runtime

I have following problem:

I have simple `.jar` program who writes in a text console..

If I start using cmd (`java -jar myProgram.jar`) the program runs **1 second**.

But I want to start program from another program using the JButton:

```
startMyProgram.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // Run a java app in a separate system process
             Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar myProgram.jar");

             // Then retreive the process output
             InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
             InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();
             System.out.println(convertStreamToString(in));
        }
 });
```

If i use a second way(JButton way), the program runs **10 second**.

Why? Why run so long?
If i start him go through another thread , it takes too long to 10s.

Comment: Can you post the code for the other program...?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post the other program code, because it's big project composed of a lot of classes.

Comment: Does the myProgram.jar output any text? Not servicing stdout/err can cause child processes to lock in some cases... A robust solution is to consume in and err streams on separate thread... I'd recommend reading http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: Yes, myProgram have output text and myProgram expires successfully.

Comment: You need to consume the input and error steams.

Comment: So I tested and I tested the methods in the link. I've found: CMD program runs over 10 seconds, 1 second run only in case if you are running in the development environment. (NETBEANS).

Comment: *This looks like a job for* a profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on StreamGobbler from [When Runtime Exec Won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) without extending Thread directly.

```
public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
    private InputStream in;
    public StreamGobbler(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        try {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // could log it here
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it to sink all the output from the streams after the exec()

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar myProgram.jar");
...
new Thread(new StreamGobbler(in)).start();
new Thread(new StreamGobbler(err)).start();;
```

Comment: So I tested and I tested the methods in the link. I've found: CMD program runs over 10 seconds, 1 second run only in case if you are running in the development environment. (NETBEANS).

Comment: Is the environment otherwise identical? Using same JDK, on same files? Same current directory?

Comment: I using same JDK (1.7), yes, same file, same directory, and i dont use memory Expansion.